# Is AWS CodeDeploy usable with ECS, AutoScaling, and a capacity provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-auto-scaling

First I'll explain a bit my case.

I'm using AWS console (website) to do everything that i'll speak about. I'm currently hosting a new project which is an API. I want a solution that can **automatically** adjust to the current trafic, and I want the deployment to be **as easy as possible**.

To host my API and others services I use an **ECS cluster**, that have currently only one service (the API). There is also an ALB (Application Load Balancer) attached to it. This service can launch from 1 to X tasks, where X is the maximum amount of instance that the Auto Scaling can launch. **The Auto Scaling** is here to adjust instances number as the number of request to the ALB increase.

Just a sidenote, there is stricly **one task per instance**. Thus, having 5 instances means 5 total tasks.

As far as I understand, for the ECS tasks to be placed correctly between instances that will be added or removed automatically, it needs a Capacity provider.

Since I want deployment to be easy, I choosed CodeBuild at first to do some stuff (like building a reusable and custom docker image for my API). I discovered that CodePipeline could also somehow wrap the "Build" process AND the "Deploy" process. But it needs a CodeDeploy to already be configured, so I tried to create one with ECS as the computing platform.

Now, the problem is that CodeDeploy need the ECS service to use Blue / Green deployment. To enable Blue / Green deployment, it seems that we are not allowed to have a Capacity Provider.

"Cluster capacity providers are **not supported** when using the blue/green deployment type."
[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-bluegreen.html#deployment-type-bluegreen-IAM)

I found a topic that seems to use the Auto Scaling as a Computing platform for the CodeDeploy application
[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html#integrations-aws-auto-scaling-behaviors)

But here they only use EC2, and not ECS...

So, is there another way maybe to achieve what i want ?

Comment: I think you already answered yourself - you can't use B/G with capacity providers.

Comment: Hm yeah, i figured that out by writing the post. Maybe i should've rephrased the title to be more like "can i get rid of the capacity provider in my case to be able to use CodeDeploy"

Comment: You don't have to use CP to use ECS, but you will have to manage scaling in/out of your instances yourself.

Comment: @Luxior Does it support now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/713) on git, ECS service now **support Blue / Green deployment with a capacity provider**.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorial-ecs-deployment.html, **CodeDeploy does not currently support Amazon ECS Capacity Provider**.