# aws ecs with capacityProviderStrategy | can deploymentController be updated once ecs service is created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

i created the ecs service with deployment controller type as ECS with capacityProviderStrategy and then wanted to modify it to CODE_DEPLOY. Is this restricted for some reason ?

- i do not see an option in the UI with modify service
- Tried the command \n aws ecs update-service --cluster=my-cluster --service=my-service --region=us-east-2 --deploymentController=CODE_DEPLOY

i get the error below
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

Unknown options: --deployment_controller={type=CODE_DEPLOY}

I tried my luck with a variation of --deployment_controller=CODE_DEPLOY however options itself is unknown to cli

Update:
During create service I noticed that CODE_DEPLOY controller is disabled when i choose capacityProviderStrategy. It looks like a limitation by design. Is it true ?
ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html

Also from aws console, it looks like deployment controller is not editable (service recreate needed) https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRMv3.png

Comment: Found thread which is pretty close to what i am looking for! answer is ecs codeploy is not supported along with oob ecs autoscaling

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66019874/is-aws-codedeploy-usable-with-ecs-autoscaling-and-a-capacity-provider